# if(rs.next()) always not working and go to else

Tags: java, mysql, oop

I work on an exame system with user login, admin login, etc.
When I check if the entered username (for example)
it doesn't return if it is already in the database
and **creates it again**!

```
try{
  //  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/big_project_3","root","");
    //imporrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrtant
    String selectquery = "select count(*)from uesrs where username='" + username + "'and password='" + password + "'";
    Statement stat=con.createStatement();
    System.out.println(selectquery);
    ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery(selectquery);
    System.out.println(rs.next());
    if(rs.next()==true){
        infoMessage("Already registered ","Welcom");
    }
    else{
        String insertQuery = "insert into uesrs values(null,'" + username_new_student.getText() + "','" + password_new_student.getText() + "','" + First_name_new_student.getText()+"')";

        stat.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
        infoMessage("info is inserted ","Alert!!!!!");
        dispose();
        user_login ul=new user_login();
        ul.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        ul.setVisible(true);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: looks like you might have a typo in your SQL. from uesrs should perhaps say "from users"

Comment: `System.out.println(rs.next());` - What do you think this is doing?

Comment: i was working with this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LTgXc2kfSbA&list=PLbPwhE_DD4JRrEsu2YscIKoCKLkHpA3Nk&index=1
with him it is worked fin !!!

Comment: but calling println on rs.next pushes things forward. Try commenting it out.

Comment: Also in place of (rs.next()==true) try (rs.next). Asking that it equal true seems stricter than asking that it not be 0.

Comment: even like this 
 ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery(selectquery);
            
            if(rs.next()){
                infoMessage("Already registered ","Welcom");
            }
            else{
                String insertQuery="insert into uesrs values(null,'"+username_new_student.getText()+"','"+password_new_student.getText()+"','"+First_name_new_student.getText()+"')";

                stat.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
                infoMessage("info is inserted ","Alert!!!!!");

it still the same

Comment: try select * not select count (*). Selecting count will always return a set with 1 record with a number, even where nothing matches (returns a 1 record set with the number 0)

Comment: thank yoooouu so match 
i found that  i am bliend hhhh
thx vary mutch

Comment: glad we were able to help. Reading this through I had one more question on the logic that you might want to check (and maybe it cannot happen). Suppose someone puts in an existing user name with the wrong password. It looks to me like your result set would be empty, so you would try to create a user with the same name and a different password -- which would not be a good thing.

Comment: Just remove the line `System.out.println(rs.next());`. That line is NOT harmless.

Answer (score 1):

Once you call `rs.next()` inside `System.out.println ()` it will move the  pointer forward. Then when you call `rs.next()` inside `if` condition there will be no more results to show.

```
try{
  //  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/big_project_3","root","");
    //imporrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrtant
    String selectquery="select count(*)from uesrs where username='"+username+"'and password='"+password+"'";
    Statement stat=con.createStatement();
    System.out.println(selectquery);
    ResultSet rs=stat.executeQuery(selectquery);

    if(rs.next() ){
        infoMessage("Already registered ","Welcom");
    }
    else{
        String insertQuery="insert into uesrs values(null,'"+username_new_student.getText()+"','"+password_new_student.getText()+"','"+First_name_new_student.getText()+"')";

     stat.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
     infoMessage("info is inserted ","Alert!!!!!");
    dispose();
    user_login ul=new user_login();
    ul.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    ul.setVisible(true);


    }

}

catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

Comment: Please see the comment by Ahmad Assaf above that when he did what you have here it still did not work. This was for sure a problem, but not the only one.